# regex extract list of strings from file

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have an input file (input.txt) which contains some data that follows a standard format similar to the following lines:

```
<descriptor/nnn> <http://www.nnn.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Politische Inklusion"@de .
<descriptor/nnn> <http://www.nnn.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Political inclusion"@en .
<descriptor/nnn> <http://www.nnn.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Radiologische Kampfmittel"@de .
```

I want to extract a list of English strings which lies between the " "@en in outputfile-en.txt, and German strings which lies between the " "@de in outputfile-de.txt

In this example outputfile-en.txt should contain:

```
Political inclusion
```

and outputfile-de.txt should contain:

```
Politische Inklusion
Radiologische Kampfmittel
```

Which regex is suitable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import re

str = """<descriptor/nnn> <http://www.nnn.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Politische Inklusion"@de .
<descriptor/nnn> <http://www.nnn.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Political inclusion"@en .
<descriptor/nnn> <http://www.nnn.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> "Radiologische Kampfmittel"@de . """

german = re.compile('"(.*)"@de')
english = re.compile('"(.*)"@en')

print german.findall(str)
print english.findall(str)
```

This would give you 
['Politische Inklusion', 'Radiologische Kampfmittel']
and 
['Political inclusion'].
Now you only have to iterate over those results and write them to the appropriate file.

Answer (score 3):

With such a simple pattern there's no need for regex at all, especially not to re-iterate over the same data to pick up different languages - you can stream parse and write your results on the fly:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:  # open the input file
    file_handles = {}  # a map of our individual output file handles
    for line in f:  # read it line by line
        rindex = line.rfind("@")  # find the last `@` character
        language = line[rindex+1:rindex+3]  # grab the following two characters as language
        if rindex != -1:  # char found, consider the line...
            lindex = line.rfind("\"", 0, rindex-1)  # find the preceding quotation
            if lindex != -1:  # found, we have a match
                if language not in file_handles:  # add a file handle for this language:
                    file_handles[language] = open("outputfile-{}.txt".format(language), "w")
                # write the found slice between `lindex` and `rindex` + a new line
                file_handles[language].write(line[lindex+1:rindex-1] + "\n")
    for handle in file_handles.values():  # lets close our output file handles
        handle.close()
```

Should be significantly faster than regex + as a bonus is that it will work with any language so if you have `...@it` lines it will save `outputfile-it.txt` as well.